# won't loop array javascript

Tags: javascript

Why cant i access my array?

```
function map(array){
    for(i=0; i <=array.length; i++){
        var location=array[i].location;
        console.log("loc"+location);
        var user = array[i].from_user;
        console.log("user"+user);
        var date = array[i].created_at;
        var profile_img = array[i].profile_img;
        var text = array[i].text;
        var contentString = text;
        //geocode(user,date, profile_img, text, contentString,location);
    }
}
```

It gives me undefined for every element.I want to access it and pass the variables to the geocode function.
data structure:

```
array=[{user: a,user_id: b,date: c,profile_img: d,text: e,contentString: f,url:
      g,location:o},{user: a,user_id: b,date: c,profile_img: d,text: e,contentString: 
      f,url:g,location:o},{user: a,user_id: b,date: c,profile_img: d,text: 
      e,contentString: f,url: g,location:s}];
```

dont worry about the values..!

I forgot to mention when i first made the post(question). the location of the array is inserted in the previous function whereas the array didn't include the attribute location from previous functions

Comment: can you provide the elements of your array

Comment: Either you posted the code incorrectly here, or you forgot to comment the second last line out, which probably causes your code to fail.

Comment: Although it's not the answer, I strongly suggest you to replace the `for` definition line with something like this: `for (var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++)`

Comment: Your code *should* work as is. It's probably the way you're calling the function.

Comment: Use `i < array.length` rather than `i <= array.length`. Other than that, the code you've posted works for `map([{ location: 'test', user: 'aaa' }, { location: 'test2', user: 'aaa2' }])` (provided a context where there are no conflicting uses of `i`, which you're creating as a global by omitting `var`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling the function, use the object literal construct enclosed in an array literal, otherwise all values will be returned as undefined. This is how you should call your function:

```
map([{ // array literal enclosing an object literal

    location   : 1,
    from_user  : 2,
    created_at : 3,
    profile_img: 4,
    text       : 5

}]);
```

Moreover, in your loop, change:

```
for (i = 0; i <= array.length; i++ ) ...
```

...to

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) ...
```

If you have a pre-defined array, name it and pass it to the function like this:

`map(arrayObj)`

Comment: this is how i get the array.so how should i access it?

Comment: You're already accessing it correctly. Inside the function, when looping, `array[i]` is the object literal; and afterwards you can obtain its properties like this: `array[i].location`, `array[i].from_user`, etc.

Comment: The only difference between this and the OP's code is this is nicely layed out. There is no difference passing **array** as opposed to passing this construct like you have.

Comment: @Aesthete I realize that and I *was* going to tell him not to use the loop, but then I thought that he might be passing a variable amount of objects in the the map invocation. So I kept it as it was. I'm also speculating that he didn't call the function correctly.

Comment: I think @David is right cause the only value I cant access now is the location which is added to the array from previous function.it wasnt there from previous functions.

Comment: @David how can i call this function so i can access all elements inside?

Comment: @anjelos Pass it like this: `map(array)`. I made a fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/kYW5k/

Comment: thank you for the help .sorry for the trouble but i still can access location

Comment: Don't worry, it's no trouble. I made a new one here -- http://jsfiddle.net/m7G9z/

Comment: @David there are some values of the locations in the array that are undefined.is this the reason I cant get the rest of the locations?

Answer (score 0):

If the `array` you pass in has a **length of 0**, the way you're looping it is going to try and access the **list element at 0**, which is going to be undefined.

However, regardless of the contents of your `array`, this line will always cause you trouble:

```
for(i=0; i <=array.length; i++)
```

When check the `length` property of your `array`, it is telling you the number of **elements in the array**. Since arrays use **0 based indexing**, you're going to **overrun** the bounds of your array with this loop everytime.

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3];
myArrary[0]; // This is 1
myArray[2]; // This is 3
```

Since you are looping between `0` and the **length of the array**, which happens to be `3`, the last element you attempt to access will no exist.

```
myArray[3]; // Undefined
```

You need to check `i < array.length` rather than `i <= array.length`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. With the provided input and function you get this:

```
loco
userundefined
loco
userundefined
locs
userundefined
```

The reason every user is coming up as undefined is because of:

```
var user = array[i].from_user;
console.log("user"+user);
```

The objects you are passing in do not have a `from_user` property, so naturally it comes up as undefined. Maybe you meant `array[i].user_id`?

Also, as Aesthete pointed out, you're running outside the bounds of your array because of the way you're checking for length. Do this instead:

```
for(var i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; i++) {
    // your code in here
}
```

Notice that I preface `i` with `var` so it does not become an implicit global. Also, I declare a second variable `n` so that you only need to access `array.length` once. This is common practice.

So, putting it all together:

```
function map(array){
    for(var i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; i++){
        var location=array[i].location;
        console.log("loc"+location);
        var user = array[i].user_id;
        console.log("user"+user);
        var date = array[i].created_at;
        var profile_img = array[i].profile_img;
        var text = array[i].text;
        var contentString = text;
        //geocode(user,date, profile_img, text, contentString,location);
    }
}
array=[{user: 'a',user_id: 'b',date: 'c',profile_img: 'd',text: 'e',contentString: 'f',url:
      'g',location:'o'},{user: 'a',user_id: 'b',date: 'c',profile_img: 'd',text: 'e',contentString: 
      'f',url:'g',location:'o'},{user: 'a',user_id: 'b',date: 'c',profile_img: 'd',text: 
      'e',contentString: 'f',url: 'g',location:'s'}];

map(array);
```

Notice I changed your object properties to strings - this is because you did not give values for these, but you probably don't want to do this. Output is:

```
loco
userb
loco
userb
locs
userb
```

All is well. If you are still getting undefined for `location` then your error must lie with the `o` property of the objects you're passing in.

Comment: Yeah you are rigth about the from_user ,i had it wrong.but still i cant get the location which is the same name in the array

Comment: That may be so, but the reason you can't get the location is not related to the code you posted.